# Spring RESTful application - POST method request body mandatory attributes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger-editor

I am building a RESTful app in Spring Boot and i want to make few attributes in my POST method's request body mandatory.

In swagger yaml, i mark them as required "true", but when i generate the classes using swagger editor, i dont see that impacting in any way, i.e i can't see even a @NotNull annotation or anything of that sort.

How do i mark them as mandatory in my java model class ? Is @NotNull the way to go?

If yes, should i do that in my request body class, or in the jpa document class or both ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `@NotNull` is a way to go.

But also You need to use `@Valid` annotation.

check example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/appointments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@Valid AppointmentForm form, BindingResult result) {
        ....
    }

    static class AppointmentForm {

        @NotNull
        private Date date;
    }
```

Comment: Sure, i will use the @Valid annotation , but i'm assuming an Exception will be thrown if the validation fails ? If so , what type of exception is it ?

Comment: This exception type could be `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. In Spring, There is @ExceptionHandler to map an exception to response HTTP code.

Comment: That helps! Thank you !